# How to deserialize DbString with Dapper

Tags: c#, string, converters, dapper

When I try to deserialize a record containing string represented by `DbString`:

```
class Record 
{
  public DbString Text {get; set;}
}
```

I get error

`{"Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Dapper.DbString'."}`

Am I misusing DbString in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use DbString in the read model (as described in the comments to my first answer) then you have the option of including a mapper from string to DbString - eg. define the class

```
public class DbStringTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<DbString>
{
    public override DbString Parse(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        var dbStringValue = value as DbString;
        if (dbStringValue != null)
            return dbStringValue;
        var stringValue = value as string;
        if (stringValue != null)
            return new DbString { Value = stringValue };
        throw new InvalidCastException("Invalid cast from '" + value.GetType() + "' to '" + typeof(DbString) + "'.");
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, DbString value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value;
    }
}
```

and then call

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler<DbString>(new DbStringTypeHandler());
```

before performing any queries.

Now the "Record" class should behave nicely as both a read model and for "writing" (ie. setting parameters).

I tested this with a SQL server connection, I *think* that it's the "SqlMapper" class that you need to call "AddTypeHandler" on regardless of what database you're talking to but there's a chance that you'll need to tweak this slightly depending upon provider.

Comment: I feel like a downvote is a little harsh (in relation to the now-removed comment asking why I had left two answers)! My original answer is, I think, valid for the original question as it was originally (and still is) stated; it would be better in most cases to using a "string" property on the Record class, rather than "DbString". However, when the question is considered in the new light (as @ironic clarified in comments on my first answer) then my second (and completely different) answer is applicable.

Comment: just in case - I did not downvote your answers! I will even upvote them because I am grateful for effort to help!

Comment: Thanks. I think it was someone who did a little hit and run on the question - down-voted the answers after seeing that I'd left two of them and left a comment asking why. When I replied to explain, they removed their comment but left the down votes. I appreciate you redressing the balance! :)

Comment: That's what I needed. I only had to add DbString.Length property reading/writing.

Answer (score 2):

The idea with Dapper is to translate query results into standard .net classes.

The "DbString" type is a Dapper class that is used for specifying parameter values in a particular manner, it's not something "standard .net".

So, instead of trying to second guess what types that Dapper might want to map things to, you should start with the simplest case since Dapper will very often just work.

In your case, your record should simply be

```
class Record 
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Dapper will do some work to try to make sure that any sensible type conversions are handled - for example, if your database field is an int then it will happily map that to an int property on the C# type *or* to a long *or* to a short or a byte (though you run the risk of an overflow exception at runtime if casting down to a smaller data type). In summary, Dapper is good to you and tries to do the hard work of type mapping - you can generally stick to the basics (string, rather than worrying about maybe using DbString) and Dapper will sort you out!

Comment: you jumped to conclusions a bit too quickly, my friend. first thing to mention - we need both reading and writing. I indeed started with using a simple string. but we are using sql anywhere data provider, which throws exception when setting DbParameter.Length to -1 (which is different from for example OdbcParameter, where it works fine). so I found that by using DbString I can workaround that problem.

Comment: also I considered using DbString's only when passing them to write queries, but that means I will have to create parameters objects manually, instead of just passing my records. with all the above in mind, if I can get confirmation that DbString is intended to be used as a field type, I can just wait for a fix. otherwise, I will probably go back to string+manual parameters object.